# Django conventional filestore location for miscellaneous files read by an app's views?

Tags: django

Is there a convention for where to put miscellaneous files which are opened and read by Django views, but which aren't python code or html templates and aren't processed by the temmplate renderer?

(In my case, I have a View which returns an application/excel .xlsx file to the user. It is generated by reading in a "template" xlsx file with lots of tricky formatting and formulae but no data values. Openpyxl is used to insert selected data from the db, and the resulting workbook is saved and sent to the user.)

Answer (score 0):

I would say this might be the media root dir, which itself is called "media", respectively some subdir of it. So in your app this is a subdirectory at <app-dir>/media or maybe /media/xlsx/.

See also here in the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/files/#file-storage